# How to deploy a Web API to my web host?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, ftp

I'm building a RESTful Web API on my local machine and it works nicely.  I want to put it on my GoDaddy web host account now.  I did this once by copy and paste file by file to the FTP site they gave me.  That worked, but it is slow and painful to do and to update when I make changes.  Is there a quicker way to publish (in Visual Studio) from my local copy to my FTP site?  If not, can you tell me which files I need to deploy for the Web API to work?  I don't think it needs all the .cs files, but I'm not sure what files it must have.

Comment: The quicker way is to leave GoDaddy.com to go to Arvixe.com.  That what I did the last time I ran on the same problem as you :).  I had the exact same problem with GoDaddy and 1and1 hosting.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd434211(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Auguste - How does it work on Arvixe?  Do they have some tool or what do you do to upload code like that?  I think Visual Studio has some way to sync my local to an FTP site, but I'm not enough of a Visual Studio guru to know that.

Comment: OK.  I'm going to go figure this out myself.  I'll bet nobody else can find the answer before I do.  (I got an A in Psych 101).

Comment: I think this may have the answer, but I'm not through reading it yet: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28WebApplicationProjects.PackagePublishOverview%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found this link about publishing a website in Visual Studio:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28WebApplicationProjects.PackagePublishOverview%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework

It didn't really solve everything for me, but I started playing around with the controls in Visual Studio.  I was able to publish my local website to FTP by right-clicking on the project node in Server Explorer and click Publish... or click Build -> Publish in the Visual Studio menu.  Fill in your FTP connection information, enter the target folder under Site Path and leave Destination URL blank (don't know, don't care).  I also unchecked "Include all databases..." in the Project Properties Page for Package/Publish Web because I didn't want to rebuild my destination database.  It worked.